# Managing a ZIP-based compression file in Java

Tags: java, file, zip, native-methods

I know that Java natively supports the ability to navigate through and ope files compressed within a ZIP file, as that is what a JAR file is. How can I utilize this to make and manage a ZIP-based file (for saving a program's state)?

Please note that the project I am working on aims to complete its goal WITHOUT ANY EXTERNAL LIBRARIES. All libraries must be already included in Java 1.6 or 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [java.util.zip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package, part of the Java standard library since JDK 1.1.

Comment: How did I miss that? *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

See [java.util.zip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html).